# Assign Value from DB using the Previously used value

Tags: mysql, sql

In my db, there is a column with user_id and and bus_no. Each user_id gets one bus_id and it will be fixed throughout the day. However my table doesn't repeat the bus_no after a while. The user_id will repeat itself according to the time the user key in their data. If i want to assign the bus_no to the user_id based on previous data, how do i do it?

| user_id | bus_no | depart |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | v808 | 02:00 |
| 1002 | x109 | 03:00 |
| 1003 | y205 | 04:00 |
| 1001 | null | 05:00 |

How do i reassign the bus_no=v808 for user_id = 1001?

I want it to be like this.

| user_id | bus_no | depart |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | v808 | 02:00 |
| 1002 | x109 | 03:00 |
| 1003 | y205 | 04:00 |
| 1001 | V808 | 05:00 |

So if I display my data in JSON, it will look like this

```
{ user_id: 1001,
  bus_no: v808,
  depart: 05:00
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `inner join` apply to a list of users with their max bus_no as follows :

```
select t.user_id, s.bus_no, t.depart
from mytable t
inner join (
  select user_id, max(bus_no) as bus_no
  from mytable
  group by user_id
) as s on s.user_id = t.user_id;
```

If you want to update the value :

```
update mytable t
inner join (
  select user_id, max(bus_no) as bus_no
  from mytable
  group by user_id
) as s on s.user_id = t.user_id 
set t.bus_no = s.bus_no
where t.bus_no is null;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/yxzLpulg)